# Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 and KB976932

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, wsus

I noticed that Microsoft recently released KB976932 which is the SP1 update for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. As we have WSUS set to download updates automatically for both of these operating systems I expected this update to be automatically pushed out however this doesn't seem to be the case as whenever I go into the update services console and search for KB976932 nothing comes up even after running a synchronization with Microsoft's update service. I know that I can manually add the update but I'm wary of doing this. What are you guys doing to push this update?

Comment: I am deploying this manually as I do not trust WSUS to automate a SP instal on critical servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SP1 has been available via Windows Update for a week or two, it was just pushed to the WSUS channel yesterday.  Try manually syncing, you should have it now.  See [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2011/03/08/windows-7-sp1-available-via-wsus.aspx) for more info.

Comment: It just showed up, thanks. I thought WSUS used the same system that Windows Update uses.

Answer (score 1):

Justin, the WSUS team delays the deployment of most major updates on the assumption that their users are in companies / enterprises, and hence need a bit more lead time to ensure that updates don't have problems and to prepare for the update processs.

This blog is invaluable for keeping abreast of what they're planning: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wsus/